# display image in mvc2 after button click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i need to display an image only after a button click in asp.net mvc2
but i am getting it even before click as well as after click
can someone give  me a solution as to why this is happenning??

Comment: Could you please supply some more infos about the process that your button should trigger and what you have tried so far? Do you just want to DISPLAY the image on click (that could be done easily with JS) oder do you actually want to LOAD it (you could do that with JS/Ajax or in a controller action)?

Answer (score 0):

Try something on the lines of:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Show it</button>

      <img src="url" style="display: none" />
<script>
    $("button").click(function () {
    $("img").show("slow");
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://api.jquery.com/show/